# Defining the order in which tests are displayed and run in Visual Studio

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, nunit, mstest, xunit

Using Visual Studio 2019 and trying out the MSTest, NUnit and xUnit testing frameworks with C#.

Say I have two methods:

```
// MSTest
[TestClass]
public class MyTests_MSTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void WantedToRunThisFirst()
    {
        // Arrange, Act, Assert...
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void ButThisRunsFirst()
    {
        // Arrange, Act, Assert...
    }
}
```

Have tried the equivalent tests and syntax in all test frameworks (i.e. MSTest, NUnit and xUnit). Tests are always displayed in the Visual Studio `Test Explorer` section in alphabetical order (i.e. with `ButThisRunsFirst` at the top). And when the tests are run, the alphabetic order is used again and `ButThisRunsFirst` runs before `WantedToRunThisFirst`.

Tests should be independent so the run order shouldn't really matter, but having the tests listed and run to match the order in the code would be nice.

Is it possible to configure the display and/or run order of unit test methods?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware with MSTest, the microsoft docs specify that they are ordered based on test name. With XUnit, there is a ITestCollectionOrderer interface but in all honesty, it's probably more hassle to set up than is necessary especially s it's just a "nice to have"
Here's the MS docs explaining how you can order unit tests in each of those frameworks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/order-unit-tests?pivots=mstest

Comment: @scottdavidwalker: Great link, thanks. TBH, that's a bit frustrating. Having the order be alphabetical by default is sensible...but why not have an option for ordering by the tests as they appear in the code top-to-bottom. And agree, implementing interfaces to specify test priority is overkill for my purposes.